# Something like pwgen-win for linux?

Tags: linux, security, passwords

Ok, is there some kind of pwd generator for linux like this one for Windows that has a nice GUI and options like this win-version has? I know that there is pwgen but as far as I know it does not support mouse/keyboard entropy and it does not have any kind of front end GUI-s.. or does it?

http://pwgen-win.sourceforge.net/

thank you

Comment: For a command-line tool, you might wanna look at `mkpasswd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some luck with [pwxgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwxgen/) on Linux.